# In Google Sheets, how can I copy a row based on a specific column value into a new tab, and then append checkboxes to the row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm trying to write a script which would allow me to copy a row into a new tab based on a specific cell value. In this case, it is a checkbox of being set to TRUE.

I have no issue with copying the row to a new sheet based on the cell value, but now I'm unsure as to how I can use `insertCheckboxes` to append 5 checkboxes to the copied row in the new sheet.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Client Database" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Referrals");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
}
}
```

Column 9 contains checkboxes which when set to true, copies the row from "Client Database" into my new tab ("Referrals").

I'm scratching my head over two things:

- What do I need to change in the code to only copy columns 1 and 4 from the original sheet? (as it is currently copying all columns from the row).
- Unless there is an easier workaround, how can I append checkboxes into the adjacent columns within the new sheet using `insertCheckboxes`? (Illustration below). This is simply to avoid having to manually insert the boxes each time (as I will not be the one using the sheet)

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Checkboxes

Add to your script

```
var checkbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
targetSheet.getRange(targetRow,3,1,4).setDataValidation(checkbox).setValue("FALSE");
```

where targetRow is the row and targetSheet the sheet where you copy

### code

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "Client Database" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Referrals");
    targetSheet.insertRowBefore(2)
    var targetRow = 2
    targetSheet.getRange(targetRow,1).setValue(s.getRange(row,1).getValue())
    targetSheet.getRange(targetRow,2).setValue(s.getRange(row,4).getValue())
    var checkbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetRow,3,1,4).setDataValidation(checkbox).setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked perfectly for me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you couldy kindly permit one more question - is there a way I can have the row added to the top of the sheet (second row, below header), rather than the bottom? I've tried removing ```getLastRow``` and added ```insertRowsBofore(2,1)```, but I can't seem to get the range and have the content added to that row instead

Comment: ok, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for your assistance once again - Still getting the hang of AppScript - I didn't think it would be something so simple as specifying the row number as I fumbled about with ```getRange```!